# Percentage calculation in Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need calculate the uptime of each system.

I have the downtime of each issue, date and system information.

I can get the total uptime of each month..

How can I calculate the uptime % of each month in Pivot table?

The uptime % = (Total Uptime - Total downtime)/Total Uptime * 100%

Please kindly help.

Ivan

Comment: Can you share your data structure and how you derive the total uptime? A small sample file or a screenshot would help. Think file sharing service.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your date format is in number form (i.e. 6/3/2015) for example, then you can create a helper column "Month", using formula `=TEXT(A1,"mmm")`(Assuming your date is in column A).

You can create a pivot table from this new set of data that include your data and the new helper column.

Place the "Month" in row labels, downtime data in values labels. This will give you a compilation of total downtime for each month.

From there, you can copy the data from the pivot table into new sheet and add in the input for the total uptime of each month that you already have. After that, all you need to do is just use simple addition / subtraction / multiplication to  perform the uptime % =formula.